# Help with Apex code to test a triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I've have a child entity  - Credit Application that is created on the parent entity - Lead(Appointment).  After the child has been created, users go in an update information on the banks used for the credit application.  I've then created a trigger to write the names of the 3 banks used back to the Lead(Appointment).
Then, after all contracts have been signed and approved, we create an installation record by checking the field Create Installation Record and updating the Lead(Appointment) record.

The test code below works for the creation of the Lead(Appointment) and it's updates.  It is failing when I try to insert the Credit Application and then update the Credit Application with the bank information.

```
@isTest
public class CreateInstall
    {
        static testMethod void createInstall()
        {
            Lead_Appointment__c Lead = new Lead_Appointment__c();
             Credit_Application__c Credit = new Credit_Application__c();

            Lead.First_Name__c = 'John';
            Lead.Last_Name__c = 'Smith';
            Lead.TSR_ID__c = 'ABC123';
            //Lead.Phone_1__c ='1231231234';

            insert Lead;

            insert credit;

            Credit.Bank_1__c = 'Admiral';
            Credit.Bank_2__c = 'Green Sky';
            Credit.Bank_3__c='Synergy';

            update Credit;

             Lead.Create_Installation_Record__c=true;

             update Lead;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where there is a parent-child relationship, you would normally set the parent ID in the lookup field of the child object before the child is inserted but I don't see that in your test. It would be something like `Credit.Lead_Appointment__c = Lead.Id;`.